# Ubuntu 20.10, hplip PyQt4 manual installation /usr/bin/ permission denied error

Tags: 20.10, hplip, sane, sip

I was a bit ambitious in trying out a non-LTS distribution of Ubuntu, upgraded to 20.10 Groovy from 20.04 focal, and suddenly `SANE` has created a permanent `'SANE_DEVICE IS BUSY'` loop, and `hplip-3.20.9` (HP Print and Imaging Driver) will not complete an install, as `PyQt4` is a required dependency for the HPLIP installer (and subsequently, for scanning to function which is the goal here)

When attempting to install `PyQt4 4.12.3` with `sip` manually from source (`PyQt4` is not available via `apt-get` and no `ppa` repository will retrieve `PyQt4`- also have added multiverse and universe repositories concurrently) at the point in which configure.py is to compile to C++, I am met with a recursive error: `/usr/bin/sip/ 'Permission Denied'`

I have attempted to chmod /usr/bin/sip to no avail, tried to execute the configure.py and configure-ng.py scripts with the same error `/usr/bin/sip 'Permission Denied'`

20.10 Groovy appears to be so new that I can find many similar issues but nothing that is the same as this. Perhaps I am overlooking some simple permissions issue with `/usr/bin/` directories?

Any help or insight is appreciated, I have spent quite a bit of time on what seems to be unobtanium but should be simple.

Comment: What was wrong with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` ?

Comment: @N0rbert `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` installs `hplip-3.20.5` whereas `hplip-3.20.9` is the newest release. Unclear if there are differences that matter, but given I am using 20.10 groovy it seems pertinent to use the newest distro of hplip. when installing either 3.20.5 or 3.20.9 from source, `PyQt4` fails to install. Printing and scanning worked fine with hplip ~3.16.x-3.18.x but ceased several weeks after installing 20.04 focal.

Comment: What is your HP printer/MFP device model?

Comment: @N0rbert, HP OfficeJet 6600, CZ155A , though I should note that I cannot rule out that `SANE` is not in fact functioning as it should - the gantry for the scanner runs through its startup sequence, but the onboard stand-alone scan and copy functions when the unit is disconnected from my workstation hang in a permanent loop when instantiated. HP support articles suggest trying alternate power sources which I have already tried with no success.